# Algorithm for Discretizing Line

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry, algebra

For some given line bound by points `(x_1, y_1)`, `(x_2, y_2)`, what algorithmic methods and approaches are available for discretizing this line into an even number of segments?

Mathematically, I suppose one would just:
(1) find the length,
(2) divide by N number of segments, and then
(3) compute the segment point from this data,

but I'm wondering if there is a better or more 'Computer Science' oriented approach to this.

I am a first year CS student so I don't know what I'm looking for, or even where to begin to look.

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to calculate and use the length.

You can find intermediate points (for N equal segments) with simple linear interpolation:

```
for i = 1 to N - 1
    Point[i].X = X1 + (X2 - X1) * i / N
    Point[i].Y = Y1 + (Y2 - Y1) * i / N
```

If you are concerned about effectiveness, precompute `X_coeff = (X2 - X1) / N` and use this value inside the cycle

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to read the two points (and N) from std::cin, then calculate the segments and finally print them to std::cout.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct point
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

int main()
{
    point P1;
    point P2;
    size_t N;

    std::cin >> P1.x >> P1.y;
    std::cin >> P2.x >> P2.y;
    std::cin >> N;

    std::vector<point> segments(N + 1);

    double x_diff = (P2.x - P1.x) / N;
    double y_diff = (P2.y - P1.y) / N;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < segments.size(); ++i)
    {
        segments[i].x = P1.x + x_diff * i;
        segments[i].y = P1.y + y_diff * i;
    }

    segments[0] = P1;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < segments.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "(" << segments[i-1].x << "," << segments[i-1].y << ") - ";
        std::cout << "(" << segments[i].x << "," << segments[i].y << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}
```